# I want to add web part in web part zone using powershell script

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, web-parts

I want to add web part in the web part zone programmatically only using **power shell script**

I am getting this exception using power shell scripting

Exception code

```
$webPart = $webpartmanager.ImportWebPart($xmlReader, $errorMsg) -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart]



Argument: '2' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Use [ref].
+ $webPart = $webpartmanager.ImportWebPart <<<< ($xmlReader, $errorMsg) -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart]
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonRefArgumentToRefParameterMsg
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried what the error message suggests (note the addition of `[ref]` before `$errorMsg`)?

```
$webPart = $webpartmanager.ImportWebPart($xmlReader, [ref]$errorMsg)
               -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart]
```